# ¿Es correcta la construcción "qué bueno que viniste"?

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, subjuntivo, pretérito, hispanoamérica

En distinos países de Hispanoamérica se utiliza la forma:

> ¡Qué bueno que viniste!

Para decir *qué bien que vinieras* o *qué bien que hayas venido*.

Al usar *que viniste* se utiliza el pretérito perfecto simple de *venir*, que es una forma verbal utilizada para acciones completadas en el pasado.
Usando la teoría, sí tiene sentido como tal, máxime cuando en Hispanoamérica normalmente se usa más el pasado simple que el compuesto (*hoy vine* en Hispanoamérica, *hoy he venido* en España). Sin embargo, en el castellano de España suena bastante extraño y diríamos *que hayas venido*, utilizando el presente del subjuntivo. Es, por tanto, no una diferencia de usar formas simples o compuestas, sino directamente de usar modos distintos.

Por tanto, ¿por qué la expresión utiliza el pretérito perfecto simple del indicativo, cuando su "equivalente" en España usa el subjuntivo?

Por cierto, ¿en qué países se usa exactamente? A mí me suena que en Argentina, pero buscando por la red encontré referencias a otro países.

Comment: Y no solamente el tiempo verbal. Aquí usaríamos "bien" en lugar de "bueno": "¡qué bien que hayas venido!". Como siempre, en la variedad está el gusto.

Comment: Una curiosidad, Alejo. ¿En España dicen "Qué bueno" solo? En Argentina decimos ambas formas, "qué bien" y "qué bueno". La primera supone el copulativo "estar", mientras que la segunda puede funcionar con "ser" o, más coloquialmente, con "estar": Es (algo) bueno que hayas venido / Está bien / bueno (coloquial) que hayas venido.

Comment: @Gustavson _qué bueno_ en España se oye poco, yo solo lo recuerdo haber escuchado en retransmisiones deportivas (de fútbol, donde suele haber bastante argentino). Lo que decimos todo el rato es _qué bien_, muchas veces solo: _-Hoy hay paella para comer. -¡Qué bien!_. Por cierto, para hablar a Carlos debes utilizar la arroba: `@Carlos`. Si no, no recibirá la notificación cuando lo menciones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mí me resulta levemente extraña (cuando la analizo) la construcción con subjuntivo. Se me ocurre que puede haber ahí una influencia de frases relacionadas que sí lo llevan indudablemente, como por ejemplo:

- *Desearía que vinieras.*
- *Sería bueno que vinieras.*
- *Estaba esperando que vinieras.*

Por supuesto en esos ejemplos el uso obligatorio del subjuntivo está dado por la construcción verbal (el modo potencial en los dos primeros casos, el verbo *esperar* en el tercero). En *Qué bueno que...* no hay un verbo principal, pero quizá los hablantes lo están asumiendo.

En Argentina decimos *Qué bueno* o *Qué bien* y generalmente *que viniste*, aunque *que hayas venido* tampoco suena raro. Ya menos gramaticalmente es común escuchar cosas como *Me gustó que viniste* o *Me encantó que viniste*, que para oídos de otras latitudes deben sonar espantosamente mal.

Comment: Efectivamente, al leer _me encantó que viniste_ di un pequeño respingo :)

Comment: Curiosamente los paisas (Colombianos del departamento de Antioquia) usamos exactamente las mismas construcciones que en Argentina.  Todo esto me suena perfectamente natural.

Comment: De todos modos, y para volver al origen de la pregunta: ¿entiendo que es gramaticalmente correcta la construcción _qué bueno que viniste_?

Answer (score 3):

Lo siguiente se aplica a México

**¡Qué bueno que viniste!** suena perfectamente natural para mi
**¡Qué bueno que hayas venido!** suena muy natural también.
**¡Qué bueno que vinieras!** suena natural aunque es menos usado.

Aquí no es tan común **bien**, pero se usa (p. ej. **¡Qué bien que viniste!**).

Sin embargo,

**¡Estoy contento de que viniste!** ya no suena muy natural.

En cambio,

**¡Estoy contento de que hayas venido!** es lo más utilizado.
**¡Estoy contento de que vinieras!** me parece natural aunque no estoy seguro de que lo usaría.

En ocasiones se suele omitir la preposición **de** (ver [queísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5))

***¡Estoy contento que hayas venido!** es también usada.

Comment: Aplica también para Colombia

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Krauss. Entonces, ¿es gramaticalmente correcta la construcción _qué bueno que viniste_?